# C++ App killing USB disk accsess?

Tags: c++, batch-file, usb, dos

I've been working on this project, and I'll do my best to explain what I'm doing.

I will run a bat file from native DOS (USB DOS Boot thumbdrive) that starts a program (SHOWDATA.EXE) and outputs some data from that program to a text file.  Then it will launch my app (compiled for DOS16Bit with Open-Watcom) which modifies a second exe file (EDITED.EXE) using information that was just previously output.  Then it should run the newly modified exe (EDITED.EXE).  My Environments for testing have been in Virtual Box and using a USB DOS bootable drive.  So far my system and program runs as intended until the line where I display 'Finished' and want to Launch the newly modified exe, I get a

> General failure reading drive C
>
> Abort, Retry, Ignore, Fail?

Virtual Box here also displays a write Error to Drive A (Floppy drive A)

If I restart the system, I can then run the newly modified file without issue and have the desired results.

Is there a problem with the way I am opening or editing or closing my file that would cause this behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)

{
    FILE * pFile;
    char data1[11];
    char data2[33];

    pFile = fopen ("testfile.exe","r+b");

    printf ("PROGAM TITLE TEXT\n");
    printf ("2013\n");
    printf ("\n");

    printf("Enter 10 Digit String from 1st filed above:\n"); //From previous program output
    scanf ("%10s",data1);         //only read 10 Chars

    printf("Enter 32 Digits from 2nd field above:\n"); //From previous program output
    scanf ("%32s",uuid);       //only read 32 Chars

    fseek (pFile,24523,SEEK_SET);//file offset location to begin write
    fputs (sn,pFile);            //Write our data!

    fseek (pFile,24582,SEEK_SET);//file offset location to begin write
    fputs (uuid,pFile);          //Write our data!

    fseek (pFile,24889,SEEK_SET);//file offset location to begin write
    fputs (uuid,pFile);          //Write our data!

    fclose(pFile);               //Close our file

    printf ("Finished\n");
    return(0);
}
```

My Bat file looks like this, where I pass a variable from text file "D.txt" to SHOWDATA.EXE and write the output to info.txt.  I then parse info.txt with a FOR /F to display only useful information that will be used to edit the second exe file (EDITED.EXE).  Then it will launch the edited exe file.

```
TYPE D.txt | SHOWDATA.EXE > Info.txt
PAUSE
MYPROGRAM.EXE
PAUSE
EDITED.EXE
```

I'm at a loss.

Comment: And you are compiling C++? Because this looks like C to me.

Comment: I suppose I should clarify, I'm compiling using Open Watcom V2 C/C++ Compiler targeting for DOS 16 Bit.

Comment: Is anything running at all?  What if you run some internal command first and pause, does that work?  Try adding `cd` and `pause` at the beginning.  Also note that the for loop will not work on DOS.

Comment: @Cookie Yes everything short of the FOR /F (NT Extension) runs as it should.  I can CD, I can DIR.  I have tried with and without PAUSE.  I haven't tried CD first.  Let me restructure into a sub dir and see how that behaves.

Comment: Right after the last PAUSE, it goes on to run EDITED.EXE, and this is where the About retry fail error comes in.  I reboot, and run EDITED.exe and it runs with the new values my program injected.

Comment: Maybe check the return value of fclose to make sure it succeeded.  Also try `fflush` before closing.